# How to get PID and Port # for a Jenkins Process

Tags: java, jenkins

I need to get PID & Port# for a Jenkins process run. If i get that PID, i can kill the process if ever i need to.

I am running the Jenkins process by below commands:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

Sometimes, Jenkins Process fail to start if that port is taken and below occurs:

```
Jenkins home directory: /Users/MacPro/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Feb 27, 2016 10:46:09 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: FAILED 
SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080:java.net.BindException: 
Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

And I know how to run the jenkins process against a specific Port#.

Need to know the commands for which PID and the port, current job is using.

Comment: I have figured out !!!  :)

Comment: you could answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command will be below:

```
ps -ef| grep jenkins
```

It will display the process id.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the job. Better to find and kill using the same command, saves time:

```
ps -Af | grep "jenkins" | grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}' | xargs kill -9
```

You can check the process before killing

```
 ps -Af | grep "jenkins" | grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}'
```

If you are running Jenkins using tomcat

```
ps -Af | grep "tomcat" | grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Please note that these commands tested on RHEL.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer to your question**
1) In Unix box, the command usage will be **ps -ef| grep jenkins**, it will display the process id (pid)
2) kill -9 (pid)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following command for a cleaner output:

```
lsof -Pni | grep mysql
```