# I would like to find the process id of a Jenkins job

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, jenkins

I would like to find a way to find the process id of a Jenkins job, so I can kill the process if the job gets hung. The Jenkins instance is on Ubuntu. Sometimes, we are unable to stop a job via the Jenkins interface. I am able to stop a job by killing the process id if I run a Jenkins job that contains a simple shell script where I manually collect the process id such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Process ID: $$"
for i in {1..10000}
do
   sleep 10;
   echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

In the command shell, I can run `sudo kill -9 [process id]`and it successfully kills the job.

The problem is, most of our jobs have multiple build steps and we have multiple projects running on this server. Many of our build steps are shell scripts, windows batch files, and a few of them are ant scripts. I'm wondering how to find the process id of the Jenkins job which is the parent process of all of the build steps. As of now, I have to wait until all other builds have completed and restart the server. Thanks for any help!

Comment: [It seems to be answered here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671874/how-to-get-pid-and-port-for-a-jenkins-process) Cheers!

Comment: Hi @gXg , thanks for your help. I ran `ps -ef| grep jenkins` and it helped me to find the Jenkins processes that were running. The problem with this is that it shows all of the running Jenkins processes. This doesn't list them by the name of the running job, which in my case was an auto-generated shell script. Upon further investigation, I determined that killing the parent process killed Jenkins so I probably need to determine another way to do this.

Comment: If I could append the BUILD_ID and the JOB_NAME to the auto-generated shell script name during execution then I think I should be able to locate the exact process and kill it. I'm not sure how to do this though. (For example, this is the info of my process that I would like to be able to search for and kill: **jenkins   3053  1831  0 10:59 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /tmp/hudson998677067093515957.sh**)

Answer (score 3):

On *nix OS you can review environment variables of a running process by investigating a `/proc/$pid/environ` and look for Jenkins specific variables like `BUILD_ID`, `BUILD_URL`, etc.

```
cat /proc/'$pid'/environ | grep BUILD_URL
```

You can do it know you `$pid` or go through of running processes.

Comment: Thanks @luka5z , I dug down and this was the output:


Now I just need to script this so I can run it against all of the running processes. I think If I can do that, I should be able to find and kill the correct processes. (Output shown in next post)

Comment: kevin@ubuntu01x64:/proc/10335$ sudo cat environ
TERM=linuxJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkinsSHLVL=1ROOT_BUILD_CAUSE=MANUALTRIGGERNODE_LABELS=masterMAIL=/var/mail/jenkinsPWD=/var/lib/jenkinsQT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5**BUILD_ID=7**BUILD_CAUSE=MANUALTRIGGERLOGNAME=jenkins**BUILD_TAG=jenkins-Wait_Job_2**-7_=/usr/bin/daemonNODE_NAME=master**BUILD_NUMBER=7**EXECUTOR_NUMBER=0SHELL=/bin/bash
...(**removed chars for brevity**) 
HUDSON_HOME=/var/lib/jenkinsXDG_SESSION_ID=c2XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/116LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

This is an update to my question. For killing hung (zombie) jobs, I believe that this will only work for cases where Jenkins is running from the same server as its jobs. I doubt this would work if you are trying to kill a hung process running on a Jenkins slave.

```
#FIND THE PROCESS ID BASED ON JENKINS JOB
user@ubuntu01x64:~$ sudo egrep -l -i 'BUILD_TAG=jenkins-Wait_Job-11' /proc/*/environ
/proc/5222/environ
/proc/6173/environ
/proc/self/environ


# ONE OF THE PROCESSES LISTED FROM THE EGREP OUTPUT IS THE 'EGREP'COMMAND ITSELF, 
# ENSURE THAT (LOOP THROUGH) THE PROCESS ID'S TO DETERMINE WHICH IS
# STILL RUNNING
user@ubuntu01x64:~$ if [[ -e /proc/6173 ]]; then echo "yes"; fi 
user@ubuntu01x64:~$ if [[ -e /proc/5222 ]]; then echo "yes"; fi 
yes

# KILL THE PROCESS
sudo kill -9 5222
```